# How do I change language in Epson Scan?

Tags: windows, drivers, language, scanner

How do I change display language of Epson Scan and related scanner utilities?

Comment: refer this may it will help you : https://files.support.epson.com/htmldocs/wfp4590/wfp4590ug/source/printers/source/printing_software/fy11_12_topics/printing_windows_business/tasks/changing_language_software_bus.html

Comment: @HarshShah – please help me to understand how the page you referred, which is related to printers, can be also used for scanners, because the question is about scanners

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It is not possible via settings. However, you can replace language files with files containing different language.

Language resource files are stored in one or both of the following directories:

```
C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\
C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\
```

You need to operate within these directories in the following way:

1. Determine 4-digit language ID of the language you currently see in the application and of the language you want to switch to.
   Use [original source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) (download the PDF from there) or some [more convenient source](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/OSLangCodes.htm) for this purpose.
2. In the above directories, locate subdirectories for both languages.
   Example: change from Slovak (`041B`) to British English (`0809`):

   ```
   C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\041B\
   C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\0809\
   C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\041B\
   C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\0809\
   ```

   - All of them are present, so the change is possible and we can continue.
3. Create backup folders for your current language and move original language files there.
   Example:

   ```
   mkdir C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\041B_backup
   move C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\041B\*.* C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\041B_backup
   mkdir C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\041B_backup
   move C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\041B\*.* C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\041B_backup
   ```
4. Copy files for your desired language to emptied folders of your current language.
   Example:

   ```
   copy C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\0809\*.* C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\local\041B
   copy C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\0809\*.* C:\Windows\twain_32\escndv\es00dd\local\041B
   ```

Now, if you start the app again, it should display everything in the new language. If not, try to determine your current language by opening `escndv.chm` in each language directory and find which language is actually displayed by the application **Help** button. Also do not get confused by English locales, because they use both `0409` and `0809` codes (US and UK), so find out which one is actually used in your computer.

- Important: Some internet guides advise to delete all language folders except `0809` in order to quickly switch to English. This actually does not fully work, tool **EPSON Scan Settings** refuses to start after such an attempt.

Comment: For Epson Scan 2, I had to make this change under C:\Program Files\epson\Epson Scan 2\Core\Resources